# Is there a hot key in IntelliJ for this action?

Tags: intellij-idea

When editing a file in IntelliJ found by searching, is there a hotkey that will navigate to that file in the project tree on left of the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View | Select In... | Project View (Alt+F1, 1 with the default Windows keymap).